# An Outlook Tasks ToDo list in PowerApps (or something else)

Tags: outlook, task, microsoft-teams, powerapps

I want to somehow create a To Do list in PowerApps, that connects to Outlook Tasks. It is avaliable as a
data source in PowerApps, so should be possible. 
I want it to be shareable. The new Microsoft To-Do app is not, so can't use that. At least not yet.

EDIT 2018-05-15: Rather go directly to the answer given here, than read the rest, if you want to make a shareable To Do list that integrates with Outlook Tasks!

There is already a To Do list template in PowerApps, but it is built on Wunderlist and I do not want this (because I can't
see how Wunderlist can connect to Outlook Tasks). Good thing is Wunderlist is shareable, though.

Nevertheless, I am trying to start with the Wunderlist template, and replace all Wunderlist calls with appropriate Outlook Tasks calls; e.g.

```
UpdateContext({MyList:Wunderlist.RetrieveLists()});;
```

with something like:

```
UpdateContext({MyList:OutlookTasks.GetAllTasks(...
```

Anyone gone through this is welcome to give a hint. I have scanned through the Internet for any instructions, or a book, but as always
I find nothing. But I know this is all so new yet.
Or else, is there another way to go?

Comment: Now it could be possible through the Microsoft To-Do connection. I instaled app on my phone with the same account as the powerapps are, than I added Microsoft To-Do connection in to PowerApps. After that I was able to add Tasks into Outlook and update it (on phone in app and even on my PC in Outlook). I did not try to retrieve list as you mention above but I think it is possible to do it. You can check this site for refs: https://www.carlosag.net/PowerApps/Connectors/Microsoft-To-Do-(Business)#_Toc61067EA9_Body
and there are some problems with text vs record fields - check this status: https:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to accomplish this. But no, the PowerApp way is not the easiest way to go (at least yet). I edited the title.
Better to use Planner and Outlook Tasks, and create a group in Microsoft Teams.
In Teams, you can easily add Planner to the tabs, and it at once gives you a To Do option. You can select exactly those people should see the list
(member of the team: all of them , some, or only yourself). It works well on the mobile, too.

At the time of this writing, an integration Planner - Outlook Tasks is not yet implemented
by Microsoft, so for now we can follow Avem Evolution's excellent videos (using Flow): 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FytBrdPHH-A

Matt Soseman's article is very useful too:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/skypehybridguy/2017/08/30/microsoft-teams-using-planner-to-stay-organized/